# Batch file redirection to text file not working inside for loop

Tags: batch-file

```
REM timestamped name of file 
set PREFIX=LINE_
set SAVESTAMP=%PREFIX%%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP: =%
set SAVESTAMP=%SAVESTAMP:,=.%.txt
echo %SAVESTAMP%

REM In H.txt, for each line grab the text after delimiter ':' and send it to file 
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('type D.txt^|find ":"') do (
    set line=%%a   
    REM#1
    echo %line% >> %SAVESTAMP%
)

REM#2
REM echo %line% >> %SAVESTAMP%   ---This output one line
```

When I use `REM#1` and comment the second `echo` outside the `for` loop, there is not file created.

But when I use `REM#2` and don't use `REM#1 echo` a file with one line is created.
Most times the file will have multiples lines written to it.

So I want this working inside the for loop.

**D.txt**

```
line1:sample1

line2:sample2

line3:sample3

line4:sample4
```

Output should be :
**Line_Date_TimeStamp.txt**

```
sample1

sample2

sample3

sample4
```

Comment: `echo %%a>>%SAVESTAMP%` should work. See also https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Tried echo %%a>>%SAVESTAMP% but its sending only 1 line to the text output. It should be sending 4 lines based on my input. For some reason its not sending more than one line from the for loop.

Comment: It looks like the issue was with the input file. It was only getting populated with one line. Hence the for loop was not printing more than one line. Once i fixed this, the for loop started inserting more lines into the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, there must be a separator (like a space) between `rem` and the text, otherwise an attempt to find and execute an executable named `rem#1.(bat,exe etc.)` is made.

Second, you need to search SO for `delayed expansion` as you are attempting to show the value of a variable (`line`) that is being modified within the `for` block.